# Extracting Protobuf custom option from file descriptor set?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Suppose we have a file named `foo.proto` defining a message and a [custom option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions):

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package foo_package;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

enum State {
    ALPHA = 0;
    BETA = 1;
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    State baz = 51234;
}

message Foo {
    string bar = 1 [ (baz) = ALPHA ];
}
```

We generate a [`FileDescriptorSet`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques) (from a directory containing [`google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto)) for this message via:

```bash
protoc -I=. --include_imports -oTMP ./foo.proto
```

**How can I extract `baz` from a message class instance in this set?** The documentation and library [(1)](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/message_factory.py), [(2)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions) suggest something like this might work:

```py
from google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2 import FileDescriptorSet
from google.protobuf.message_factory import GetMessages

with open("TMP", mode="rb") as f:
    fds = FileDescriptorSet.FromString(f.read())

    messages = GetMessages([file for file in fds.file])
    extensions = messages["foo_package.Foo"].DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name["bar"].GetOptions().Extensions
```

but the resulting object is empty. [#6662](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6662) implies using a `DescriptorPool` should resolve it, but that also doesn't seem to work (empty object, as well).

Comment: I randomly stumbled across this question looking for something else, but also recently had this issue and figured it out! Will write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GetOptions()` will give you the built-in *non-extended* type `google.protobuf.FieldOptions`. In the protobuf implementation, `GetOptions()` constructs a message of the built-in type `google.protobuf.FieldOptions`, and then parses the bytes into that struct. You can see that here in the Python impl, for e.g.: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/5df4c2ec9426b06dfe8a019ddcf1509b8816cebe/python/google/protobuf/descriptor.py#L167-L170

The message descriptor will indeed have the options you defined; you can print the serialized version of the field options and you will see them, but they are *not* parsed into the resulting field options. The non-extended type does not describe those additional fields, so they're ignored.

What you actually want is to parse the options using *your* extended version of `google.protobuf.FieldOptions`.

I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way to do this, but what worked for me is to re-serialize the options, and then parse them using the dynamic version of your extended FieldOptions. Overall that looks something like this:

```py
messages = GetMessages([file for file in fds.file])
Foo = messages["foo_package.Foo"]
FieldOptions = messages["google.protobuf.FieldOptions"]

bar_builtin_opts = Foo.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name["bar"].GetOptions()
bar_opts = FieldOptions()
bar_opts.ParseFromString(bar_builtin_opts.SerializeToString())
```

Note that this process is the same for all option types (field options, message options, etc).

You may have to create your own descriptor pool & message factory that is separate from the default ones if you run into issues redefining existing message types, though that's as simple as

```py
pool = DescriptorPool()
for fd in fds.file:
    pool.Add(fd)
factory = MessageFactory(pool)
messages = factory.GetMessages([file.name for file in fds.file])
```